# how does docker net=host handle port conflict

Tags: docker

How does Docker handle `docker run -d --net=host <image>` if I run 2 images that have the exact same port EXPOSEd?

For example, if I run:

```
$ docker run -d --net=host nginx
$ docker run -d --net=host nginx
$ docker run -d --net=host httpd

# I now have 3 containers running, all of which EXPOSE port 80
# what does the following return?
$ curl http://localhost:80/
```

What response do I get? The first `nginx`? The second `nginx`? The Apache `httpd`? And how does Docker manage it under the covers? There is no NAT involved since I did `--net=host`

Comment: can you post `docker port container_id` for the 3 containers?

Comment: OK, this is really strange, but.... the question is irrelevant. For some odd reason, the first times I ran the experiment, all the containers started. Right now, as I am trying to get you `docker port <CID>`, the second one fails with `(98)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address [::]:80` which it should!

Answer (score 1):

Well, I have my answer. Just like a process that tries to bind to a port already in use will fail with `EADDRINUSE`, so too will a container that tries to bind to a port already in use on the host if `--net=host`.